# SUPERPOSICION DE MAPA (LEAFLET) ENCIMA DEL NAVBAR (BOOTSRAP)

Tags: bootstrap, leaflet, navbar

Como se ve en la imagen el mapa se superpone a la barra de Menu.
No sabria como corregir eso

[image: SUPERPOSICION MAPA]

El mapa esta descripto como

```
<style>
  #map { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 480px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888;
 }
</style>
```

El codigo completo para mostrar es medio engorroso pero quizas ustedes sepan como solucionarlo. Gracias!

Comment: ya probaste con un `z-index` en tu barra de navegación?

Comment: Revisa el atributo [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/position) tanto en el mapa como en tu menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sería de gran ayuda que mostraras el html para saber cómo está estructurado el maquetado, pero por lo pronto, puedes agregar un margen superior div#mapa para compensar. usando margin-top: 10px;

Answer (score -1):

Lo solucione agregando la clase `navbar-fixed-top` :)